# Scala Akka Streams project fails to compile, "value ~> is not a member of akka.streams.Outlet[In]"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, akka, akka-stream

I am using the Akka Streams API in a Scala project, working in Intellij IDEA with the SBT plugin. I have a worker pool Flow as described here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html. Here is my code:

```
package streams

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Balance, Flow, GraphDSL, Merge}
import akka.stream.{FlowShape, Graph}

object WorkerPoolFlow {
  def apply[In, Out](
    worker: Flow[In, Out, Any],
    workerCount: Int):
  Graph[FlowShape[In, Out], NotUsed] = {

    GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>

      val balance = b.add(Balance[In](workerCount, waitForAllDownstreams = true))
      val merge   = b.add(Merge[Out](workerCount))

      for (i <- 0 until workerCount)
        balance.out(i) ~> worker.async ~> merge.in(i)

      FlowShape(
        balance.in,
        merge.out)
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason the project is now failing to compile, giving this error: `value ~> is not a member of akka.stream.Outlet[In]`.

It compiled fine until today. The only change I am aware of making is installing a Scala linter plugin `scalafmt`, and importing a few new libraries in `build.sbt`. Here is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "myProject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

unmanagedJars in Compile += file("localDep1.jar")
unmanagedJars in Compile += file("localDep2.jar")

libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.6"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.6"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.6" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.5.6" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.47deg" %% "fetch" % "0.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

I have tried reloading SBT, building from SBT outside of IDEA, removing and re-adding dependencies, and cleaning the project, with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import `GraphDSL.Implicits._`:

```
object WorkerPoolFlow {
  def apply[In, Out](
    worker: Flow[In, Out, Any],
    workerCount: Int):
  Graph[FlowShape[In, Out], NotUsed] = {
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well then. I think I've been staring at screens too long. Thanks for the sanity check!